# Bluemix : cf logs command taking 10-15 mins to load

Tags: cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

This just started today but it seems to be consistent across all of my Bluemix apps, running `cf logs <appname> --recent` is taking 10+ minutes to load, making debugging a grueling experience.

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the logergator service responds slower than normal. Can you try again in a couple of hours?